# android gridview items different sizes

Tags: android, android-gridview

My problem is that some of my gridview items have a different height than others. I want that all items have the same width and height.
Here is the code for the item layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/container_categoria"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="20dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:background="#232323"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView5"
        android:layout_width="75dp"
        android:layout_height="75dp"
        android:paddingBottom="5dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/category_name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Centro de Investigação de Exemplo" />

</LinearLayout>
```

And here is my main layout file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" >


    <GridView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:numColumns="auto_fit"
        android:verticalSpacing="5dp"
        android:horizontalSpacing="5dp"
        android:id="@+id/gridView"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

And here is an image showing the problem:
[image with problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N6QZm.png)

Answer (score 0):

It is happens because your TextView, has different text length, try this easy way (in your item xml):

```
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/category_name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:text="Centro de Investigação de Exemplo" />
```

Or use fixed height of GridView items like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/container_categoria"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="300dip"
    android:padding="20dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:background="#232323"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView5"
        android:layout_width="75dp"
        android:layout_height="75dp"
        android:paddingBottom="5dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/category_name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Centro de Investigação de Exemplo" />

</LinearLayout>
```

You may calculate height programatically in your code.

Comment: it fixes the item height problem but cuts the text short if it has more than  1 lines. If i set to 3 the height problem continues

Comment: Or you can use fixed height in your root GridView items: 
    android:layout_height="300dip" or other values

Comment: i would like to avoid fixed heights to be easier to scale on tablet devices

Comment: so, you can calculate height in code or use autoscale textview: https://github.com/grantland/android-autofittextview

Comment: great idea, but the minimum sdk for this is 14 and i have to have a minsdk of 9 :(

Comment: maybe other way: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5535672/2738172 I wrote only strategy to how this realize

Answer (score 0):

This is because of your TextView.
As far as I can see, where you have 3 lines of text the item is bigger, and where you have only 2 the item is smaller.
The obvious choice here would be to change the LinearLayout of the item to a RelativeLayout and scale the boxes accordingly. Or you can set a fixed Height to your layout.

Comment: what do you mean by "scale the boxes accordingly"?